# I am stuck, trying to make a turn based game but have been having trouble ending a turn and starting a new one

Tags: java, loops

I can end the first. I am trying to make it on odd turns player goes and even turns CPU goes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random = new Random();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String mage = "mage";

    System.out.println("mage, warrior, assassin, ranger?");

    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    int playerAttackDice = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
    int cpuAttackDice = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
    int playerDefenseDice = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
    int cpuDefenseDice = random.nextInt(5) + 1;

    int turn = 1;


    while(mage.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        Mage player = new Mage();
        Warrior CPU = new Warrior();

        System.out.println("You have selected: mage");

        System.out.println("Your Attack Power is: "  + player.getMageAttack());
        System.out.println("Your Defense is: " + player.getMageDefense());
        System.out.println("Your Health is: " + player.getMageHealth());

        System.out.println("Your enemy is a: warrior");

        System.out.println("Enemy Attack Power is: "  + CPU.getMageAttack());
        System.out.println("Enemy Defense is: "  + CPU.getMageDefense());
        System.out.println("Enemy Health is: "  + CPU.getMageHealth());

        System.out.println();
```

This is where the turn begins. I was trying to set it to make it player goes on odd numbers in the when the CPU goes. Am I even approaching this in the right way? Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
        while(player.mageHealth != 0) {
            System.out.println("Your health is: " + player.mageHealth);

            for(turn = 1; turn % 1 ==0; turn++) {
            if(turn % 1==0) {
                System.out.println("Your dice roll is:" + playerAttackDice);
                int playerDamage = playerAttackDice + player.mageAttack;
                int cpuDefense = cpuDefenseDice + CPU.mageDefense;
                System.out.println(playerDamage);
                System.out.println(cpuDefense);

                System.out.println("CPU health is: " + (CPU.mageHealth + cpuDefense - playerDamage ));
                return;
            }

            }
            turn++;
            for(turn = 2; turn % 2 ==0; turn++) {
            while(turn % 2==0) {
                System.out.println("CPU dice roll is:" + cpuAttackDice);
                System.out.println("Your dice roll is:" + playerDefenseDice);
                int cpuDamage = playerDefenseDice + player.mageAttack;
                int playerDefense = cpuAttackDice + CPU.mageHealth;
                System.out.println(cpuDamage);
                System.out.println(playerDefense); 
            }
            }



        }

        System.out.println("end loop");
        break;

}
```

}

Comment: No. The first for loop will not run at all (it will loop zero times), the second for loop will run only once, but the while loop inside it is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Player and CPU to play their move one after another - just put their actions one after another with no inner loops and complex conditions around

```
while (!game.isOver()) {
 player.makeMove();
 cpu.makeMove();
}
```

or having your code there

```
while(player.mageHealth > 0) { // game over condition
    //player move
    System.out.println("Your health is: " + player.mageHealth);

    System.out.println("Your dice roll is:" + playerAttackDice);
    int playerDamage = playerAttackDice + player.mageAttack;
    int cpuDefense = cpuDefenseDice + CPU.mageDefense;
    System.out.println(playerDamage);
    System.out.println(cpuDefense);

    System.out.println("CPU health is: " + (CPU.mageHealth + cpuDefense - playerDamage ));

    //cpu move
    System.out.println("CPU dice roll is:" + cpuAttackDice);
    System.out.println("Your dice roll is:" + playerDefenseDice);
    int cpuDamage = playerDefenseDice + player.mageAttack;
    int playerDefense = cpuAttackDice + CPU.mageHealth;
    System.out.println(cpuDamage);
    System.out.println(playerDefense);

    player.mageHealth = player.mageHealth + playerDefence - cpuDamage;
}
```